# perl how to determine the type of a "raw symbol"

Tags: perl, typeglob

Apparently, it's possible to store a "raw symbol" (as opposed to a reference to a symbol) in a scalar variable and use it in scalar contexts.

How do you determine whether a scalar-valued expression is one of these symbols?

They appear to stringify to `"*name_of_symbol"` and `ref` returns `""`. However `Data::Dumper` is also able to determine that it isn't a string and prints it without quoting.

Is it possible to determine when you have a raw symbol? How is `Data::Dumper` doing it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local *foo = \4;

my $sym = *foo;

printf "((%s))\n", $sym;
printf "[[%s]]\n", (ref $sym);
print Dumper($sym);
```

produces:

```
((*main::foo))
[[]]
$VAR1 = *::foo;
```

I was expecting some dedicated value for `ref $sym`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`*foo` is called a typeglob, or glob for short. A glob is reflection of an instance of a C structure that contains a slot for each type of value —a "glob" of "types", one might say— and forms the basis of the symbol table.

They are weird because they are both a type of variable (`*foo`) and a type of value (value of `$sym`), though this isn't relevant here.

To determine if a value is a glob, you can use the following:

```
use Scalar::Util qw( reftype );

( reftype(\$sym) // '' ) eq 'GLOB'
```

You could also use

```
ref(\$sym) eq 'GLOB'   # Fooled by bless(\$sym, 'GLOB')
```